# How to integrate the AddThis in iPhone Application using AddThis SDK ?

Tags: ios

Please provide the link to Download the AddThis SDK. Please Tell me how to integrate the AddThis SDk into iOS Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [addThis Doku](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381270-addthis-for-ios-quick-start-guide#.UOrPvdf2Qcu) should help you. Part 3 should answer your question.

Comment: Please use the following link for download the AddThis SDK http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381273-addthis-for-ios-documentation#.UbLLuSvVfR1